# presentingViewController shows up as null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have three view controllers that are connected to a tab bar controller, which I thought should automatically set the presentingViewController/presentedViewController. However, when I toggle between my view controllers and I log [self presentingViewController], it logs null. I put the log in my viewDidAppear methods in each of the view controllers.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    NSLog(@" my presenting view controller is %@", [self presentingViewController]);

}
```

Output:

```
my presenting view controller is (null)
```

Comment: The presentingViewController property is set to a controller which presented you -- that means it did so with a modal presentation or segue. Switching tabs in a tab bar controller isn't a presentation.

Comment: No, it's not "presented", it appears on screen. A presentation, in the context of presentingViewController and presentedViewController means a modal presentation. What is your intent here? Are you trying to figure out which tab you came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know which tab you came from, then you should subclass the tab bar controller, and set it as its own delegate. Create an integer property, oldIndex which you can set before the tab switch in the delegate method, tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:.

```
@interface RDTBC () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation RDTBC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}


- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    self.oldIndex = self.selectedIndex;
    return YES;
}
```

Then in your view controller, you can get it like this,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%ld",[(RDTBC *)self.tabBarController oldIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try and will update you.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably not a good idea to make one tab's behavior dependent on what tab was last shown. Tabs are designed to function independently.

Comment: I have data that need to be accessed across multiple tabs. So for my implementation, my tabs do depend on each other.